# echo mysql DATE(table_date) undefined constant

Tags: php, mysql

`print_r($line)` show  `[DATE( table_date )] => 2013-07-30`

However when I echo it it shows undefined constant, what's the appropriate syntax?

```
echo $line[DATE(table_date)];
echo $line[DATE('table_date')];
echo $line['DATE(table_date)'];
```

is all wrong. Why it act so as in my knowledge if printr show [var1] then we should be able to do `echo $line[var1]`, this is how php work isn't it.

---

and by the way I'm solving it by using  `DATE(table_date) AS vardate` , however I will like to know why the above syntax not functioning

Comment: Try: echo $line['vardate']; You have given this field name by DATE(table_date) AS vardate in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > however I will like to know why the above 
> >     syntax not functioning php mysql

You're missing the space `[DATE( table_date )]` on your variables:

```
echo $line['DATE( table_date )'];
```

That's why it doesn't echo.

Alternatively you can also try:

```
foreach ($data as $value)
{
    echo $value, "\n";
}
```

Comment: So its php recognize variable syntax problem, quite a strange reason for malfunction as `()` should be recognize as function by default

Comment: @Anonymous not inside single quotes and the representation of `print_r` does not evaluate it either.